# ¿Como hacer un UPDATE a una tabla para ordenar una columna? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo, openerp

Estoy trabajando en Odoo 12 intentando ordenar una tabla a nivel base de datos esta tabla es `product.supplierinfo` y la columna que debe ordenarse es `date_start`, pero quiero ordenar la tabla de manera masiva y de forma ascendente.

Cabe mencionar que no quiero realizar una consulta con:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_supplierinfo 
WHERE product_tmpl_id = 67247 
ORDER BY date_start ASC
```

Si no ordenar de forma permanente la columna `date_start`

Les dejo a continuación una imagen de la tabla que comento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo lo que pretendes hacer, para eso es el order by

Comment: La verdad no entiendo porque no queres usar `ORDER BY`, pero supongamos que tenes un buen motivo, lo que podrías hacer es copiar los datos y reinsertarlos ordenados... el problema que vas a tener eventualmente es si insertan un datos con fecha anterior. Si esto sucede, vas a tener que repetir el proceso... esto tiene pinta de no ser una buena idea. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a0c923/8)

Comment: no es que no quiera usar `ORDER BY`, más bien no quiero solo realizar una consulta, si no modificar la tabla permanentemente para que siempre esté ordenada de manera ascendente, incluso si se agregan nuevos registros se ordenen de la misma forma

Comment: Pon ese campo como llave primaria

Comment: @AnibalWB sigo sin entender que ganas con eso. El orden es algo "estético", mañana podes cambiarlo.

Comment: Las tablas no tienen un orden físico o "permanente", a nivel conceptual en SQL el orden en una tabla solo existe cuando usas la cláusula `ORDER BY`.

Comment: tienen razón, debo ordenar los registros a nivel programación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el campo reservado _order para tu modelo 'product.supplierinfo', de esta manera según lo que necesitas:

```
Class ProductSupplierinfo(models.Model):
    _name = 'product.supplierinfo'
    _order = 'date_start ASC'
```

De esta manera cualquier vista o consulta que hagas a traves de Odoo(search, browse) estará ordenado bajo la definición del campo `_order`.

Espero que esta respuesta pueda ayudarte.